# Nextjs how to remove html class from another page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How can I add an only home-landing class on the index page and other pages removed from HTML class? Using nextjs.

```
render() {
  return (
    <html class="home-landing">
      <Head>
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"
          href="../static/css/fonts/montserrat/montserrat.css"
        />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: You could use [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet#as-react-components) and change the html attributes on different pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can define global styles only in your `index` component.

```
render() {
 return (
  <html>
    <Head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/fonts/montserrat/montserrat.css" />

    </Head>
    <body>
      <Main />
      <NextScript />
    </body>
    <style global jsx>{`
        html {
            // Put here the CSS you want to apply for html tag
        }
    `}
    </style>
  </html>
);
}
```

See [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/#built-in-css-support)